# Revert a SVN commit to properties in Subversive

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I have updated the SVN properties via clicking on Team->Show Properties on a folder in my branch under Eclipse Juno. Is there a way to revert this? Is this just like the usual commit

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove that property change? Just revert the file/directory where that property is set.

Properties in Subversion are like file changes. When you change the property on a file (or directory), you must commit that file (or directory) as if you modified the actual contents of the file itself. Taking a look at the history log will show you that the file was changed, but if you diff that file to the previous version, it will show you just the property was changed.

Comment: I have been doing it at the folder level so I tried doing that but Eclipse tells me there are no files to revert to